# POSTGRE SQL insert into error

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have this sql command (output in the browser)

```
insert into xtable (type, moduleid, question, answers, quiz_id) values('poll', 1, 'test?', '["teest?","teeest?"]', 1)
```

It gives me this result when running it on postgresql interface

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "into" LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS
>   total FROM (insert into xtable(t...

I am executing this from a php file, so don't tell me to uncheck paginate results ( that will work but not if i run it from a php file )

This is the php part

```
$db->setQuery( "insert into xtable(type, moduleid, question, answers, quiz_id) values('".JRequest::getVar('type')."', ".JRequest::getVar('moduleid').", '".addslashes(JRequest::getVar('question'))."', '".$answers_str."', ".$quizid.")" );
$db->query();
```

Comment: The error says you have an additional `select count(*)` in the query. Please post the entire query if you want help with it.

Comment: You're still omitting something. The `select count(*)` query is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: i don't execute any count(*) . That appears only after i execute it on the postgresql sql command interface. As far as I read about this. I can get rid of the count(*) by unchecking the Paginate Result on postgres when runninh the query . But that wont help if i am executing from a php file

Comment: Let me just repeat for you . I put this command in the postgresql interface for sql command : insert into xtable (type, moduleid, question, answers, quiz_id) values('poll', 1, 'test?', '["teest?","teeest?"]', 1) . AND IT GIVES ME THAT SYNTAX ERROR

Comment: as show here : http://i.imgur.com/PlZnmJ1.png 
ignore table name

Comment: solved. id column was not auto increment

Answer (score 1):

I think this error from phpPgAdmin and your query is correct.

Also, I suggest you add to your insert query `RETURNING quiz_id` it can help count result in phpPgAdmin and try to submit this bug to phpPgAdmin developers.

Comment: i found the answer . My id column was not auto increment